# How to add ctrl+v in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, textbox, copy-paste

I'm wondering how to add <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> in pygame. I made a text box that will help. I'm just wondering how to copy the data from my clipboard.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What *exactly* are you trying to do, and what have you done so far to try and solve the problem?

Comment: im trying to make a fonction that will make the computer search in the clipboard history to look at the last copied text

Comment: you may need to install module which can get/set data directly from clipboard (without `Ctrl+V`) - like [clipboard](https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/). Eventually in PyGame you can assign `Ctrl+V` to function which will use module `clipboard` to get data from clipboard

Comment: see also [pygame.scrap](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/scrap.html) - it seems it can get data from clipboard. So you have to only check in `for event in pygame.event.get()` if `V` was pressed and check `pygame.key.get_mods()` to check if `Ctrl` was also pressed (or rather `pygame.KMOD_CTRL`). See examples in doc [key modifiers label](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#key-modifiers-label)

Comment: There *is* a `pygame` module for clipboard support — see [`pygame.scrap`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/scrap.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is module [pygame.scrap](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/scrap.html) to get/set clipboard but (on Linux) I had to use

```
pygame.scrap.get("text/plain;charset=utf-8").decode()
```

instead of

```
pygame.scrap.get(pygame.SCRAP_TEXT)
```

And I needed to set first

```
pygame.scrap.init()
pygame.scrap.set_mode(pygame.SCRAP_CLIPBOARD)
#pygame.scrap.set_mode(pygame.SCRAP_SELECTION)
```

---

You can check `Ctrl+V` in loop `for event in pygame.event.get()` with

```
if (event.key == pygame.K_v) and (event.mod & pygame.KMOD_CTRL):
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

FPS = 25

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

pygame.scrap.init()
pygame.scrap.set_mode(pygame.SCRAP_CLIPBOARD)
#pygame.scrap.set_mode(pygame.SCRAP_SELECTION)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    # --- events ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            
            elif event.key == pygame.K_v and event.mod & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:
                print('Clipboard:', pygame.scrap.get(pygame.SCRAP_TEXT))
                print('Clipboard:', pygame.scrap.get("text/plain;charset=utf-8").decode())
                
                for t in pygame.scrap.get_types():
                    r = pygame.scrap.get(t)
                    print('>', t, r)
                    
    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- FPS ---

    ms = clock.tick(FPS)
    
# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

---

In PyGame repo on GitHub I found also [examples/scrap_clipboard.py](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/main/examples/scrap_clipboard.py)

---

You may also use modules like [clipboard](https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the clipboard content use `pyperclip`

here is a link for installation : [pyperclip pip link](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/)

you can copy/pasted & edit clipboard content

Comment: better put information how to install directly in answer instead of link to external portal

Comment: pip install pyperclip

Comment: you should put it in question, not in comment - to make answer more useful for other users.